# How to convert JObject to array in VB.net?

Tags: json, vb.net

I'm trying to convert a JObject into a specific property list but I don't know how to achieve this.

Here is the JSON :

```
{

"response":{
    "result":1,
    "resultcount":1,
    "collectiondetails":[
        {
            "publishedfileid":"1717998413",
            "result":1,
            "children":[
                {
                    "publishedfileid":"109643223",
                    "sortorder":1,
                    "filetype":0
                },
                {
                    "publishedfileid":"1498270631",
                    "sortorder":2,
                    "filetype":0
                },
                {
                    "publishedfileid":"162218499",
                    "sortorder":3,
                    "filetype":0
                },
                {
                    "publishedfileid":"1419266438",
                    "sortorder":4,
                    "filetype":0
                },
                {
                    "publishedfileid":"245482078",
                    "sortorder":5,
                    "filetype":0
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
}
```

I would like to do a list of the value of "publishedfileid" property.

I started doing this `Dim rawJson = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse(jsonString)` but I don't know what to do after that.

Thank you for taking time to answer me.
Regards,

Comment: Why don't you use a class structure/mode to deserialize your JSON? In this case, you can use Visual Studio's `Paste Special -> Paste JSON as Classes`; the JSON is simple, it'll get it right. Deserialize passing the `Rootobject` of the model. You can then access the objects as property values as usual.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved thanks to [@Jimi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7444103/jimi)

Edited my old code to `Dim rawJson = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of Rootobject)(jsonString)` and looped through `rawJson.response.collectiondetails(0).children`